# How to map same character two times in Elasticsearch charFilter

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using greek characters in my indices and I am trying to search with greek tones.For example if I search with "παλια" I want to get back "παλια" and "παλιά".I am trying to create double mapping for character α but I a get as error "match \"α\" was already added".Here is my code :

```
 var response = client1.CreateIndex("thetrialindex",
            th =>
                th.Settings(
                    s =>
                        s.Analysis(
                            a =>
                                a.Analyzers(
                                        an =>
                                            an.Custom("my_analyzer",
                                                cu => cu.Tokenizer("keyword").CharFilters("my_char_filter"))
                                               )
                                    .CharFilters(c1=>c1.Mapping("my_char_filter", ma1=>ma1.Mappings("α => ά","α => α")))
                                                                                    )));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is using IcuTransform with the languages you need.
For example for translating latin characters to greek you can use something like that:

```
.IcuTransform("latingreek", lg => lg.Id("Latin-Greek; NFD; [:Nonspacing 
Mark:] Remove; NFC").Direction(IcuTransformDirection.Forward))
```

and add this to your index and search analyzer.